# Google Voice texts delivered hours late/not at all

Tags: google-voice, background-data

I use a Google Voice phone number to receive texts, and I have the Google Voice app installed on my device (Atrix, OS:2.3.3).

For some reason lately when someone texts my Google Voice account it's not getting sent to my phone. For example:

- I got a text at 9:00 this morning (time is now 1PM)
- If I visit voice.google.com, I see I have a text in my inbox.
- If I open the Google Voice app on my phone, it does the 'synchronizing' spinning wheel animation for a few seconds and then I get the 'new text' notification, which is now 4 hours late.

In my Google Voice app's options, I have `Background data: Enabled`. Why isn't it pushing my texts when they are received? I get Gmail messages delivered to my phone near instantly, but I'm not getting the same behavior with GV.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you also enabled `auto-sync`. It might also be a problem with the network specially if 3G coverage in your area is spotty

Comment: I don't recall seeing such an option such as 'auto-sync', can you say where you saw it? The 3G in my area is pretty solid, I've usually got 4 or 5 bars.

Comment: It's in the Settings -> Accounts & sync -> Activate auto-sync, just right under Background Data. But if you're on ICS or newer, tap your account and see if data sync for each items are checked

Comment: Hmm, you must have a different version than me, because I don't see any such menus. Under settings I just have `Accounts`, and `Battery & Data Manager`. Under `Data Delivery`, I have `Background data` checkbox, but there's nothing under it called auto-sync. Maybe it's the motorola skin, not sure. Based on the number of other complaints I see about this issue I'll have to guess it's some flaw with the app and not with the android environment, but hard to be sure.

Comment: my Settings is AOSP-based so your settings must be running on Moto's skin. Also is this issue just recent?

Comment: I have the same problem on my Moto Bionic (running JB 4.1) with Google Voice text and voicemail notifications.

Comment: If I recall there was an update recently that addressed this. Is this still an issue for you?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure why it happens, but I've experienced the same issue in the past with the very same phone.  It usually happened when I was travelling, such that once I arrived at a new destination, I'd suddenly get text messages delivered.  The issue did seem to go away when I installed a custom rom (the latest Cyanogenmod at the time).  I've since gotten another phone and have never experienced the issue.  If you're feeling brave, I recommend flashing a newer rom.